# How to prevent hadoop fail job due to failed reduce task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I have running a `s3distcp` job in `AWS EMR hadoop 2.2.0` version. And the job keep failed with a failed reducer task after 3 attempts. I also tried both:

```
mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent
mapreduce.reduce.failures.maxpercent
```

to be 50 to the oozie `hadoop` action configuration and `mapred-site.xml`. But still the job failed.

And here are the logs:

> 2015-10-02 14:42:16,001 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:
>   Task Id : attempt_1443541526464_0115_r_000010_2, Status : FAILED
>   2015-10-02 14:42:17,005 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: 
>   map 100% reduce 93% 2015-10-02 14:42:29,048 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 98% 2015-10-02
>   15:04:20,369 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:  map 100%
>   reduce 100% 2015-10-02 15:04:21,378 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job: Job job_1443541526464_0115 failed
>   with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1443541526464_0115_r_000010
>   Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1
>
> 2015-10-02 15:04:21,451 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:
>   Counters: 45
>           File System Counters
>                   FILE: Number of bytes read=280
>                   FILE: Number of bytes written=10512783
>                   FILE: Number of read operations=0
>                   FILE: Number of large read operations=0
>                   FILE: Number of write operations=0
>                   HDFS: Number of bytes read=32185011
>                   HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
>                   HDFS: Number of read operations=170
>                   HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
>                   HDFS: Number of write operations=28
>           Job Counters
>                   Failed reduce tasks=4
>                   Launched map tasks=32
>                   Launched reduce tasks=18
>                   Data-local map tasks=15
>                   Rack-local map tasks=17
>                   Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=2652786
>                   Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=65506584
>           Map-Reduce Framework
>                   Map input records=156810
>                   Map output records=156810
>                   Map output bytes=30892192
>                   Map output materialized bytes=6583455
>                   Input split bytes=3904
>                   Combine input records=0
>                   Combine output records=0
>                   Reduce input groups=0
>                   Reduce shuffle bytes=7168
>                   Reduce input records=0
>                   Reduce output records=0
>                   Spilled Records=156810
>                   Shuffled Maps =448
>                   Failed Shuffles=0
>                   Merged Map outputs=448
>                   Failed Shuffles=0
>                   Merged Map outputs=448
>                   GC time elapsed (ms)=2524
>                   CPU time spent (ms)=108250
>                   Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=14838984704
>                   Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=106769969152
>                   Total committed heap usage (bytes)=18048614400
>           Shuffle Errors
>                   BAD_ID=0
>                   CONNECTION=0
>                   IO_ERROR=0
>                   WRONG_LENGTH=0
>                   WRONG_MAP=0
>                   WRONG_REDUCE=0
>           File Input Format Counters
>                   Bytes Read=32181107
>           File Output Format Counters
>                   Bytes Written=0 2015-10-02 15:04:21,451 INFO [main] com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp: Try to
>   recursively delete
>   hdfs:/tmp/218ad028-8035-4f97-b113-3cfea04502fc/tempspace 2015-10-02
>   15:04:21,515 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded &
>   initialized native-zlib library 2015-10-02 15:04:21,516 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor
>   [.deflate] 2015-10-02 15:04:21,554 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:
>   Task:attempt_1443541526464_0114_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the
>   process of committing 2015-10-02 15:04:21,570 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task
>   attempt_1443541526464_0114_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
>   2015-10-02 15:04:21,584 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved
>   output of task 'attempt_1443541526464_0114_m_000000_0' to
>   hdfs://rnd2-emr-head.ec2.int$ 2015-10-02 15:04:21,598 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task
>   'attempt_1443541526464_0114_m_000000_0' done. 2015-10-02 15:04:21,616
>   INFO [Thread-6] amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver: Inside MetricsSaver
>   Shutdown Hook

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try cleaning the hdfs://tmp directory. Just take a backup of the directory as some other applications use tmp directory and in case you face any issues you can replace the tmp directory.